# To select count of products across multiple campaigns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

`Campaign has a project_id column so the hierarchy is like a project has multiple campaigns and a campaign has multiple products.`

Now I have the below scenario:
I have a UI with the list of products where a particular product can be selected for a campaign. But there is a check which needs to be executed on every selection of product for a campaign. The check is to count the number of `unique products` across all campaigns for a particular project. It should not allow selecting a product if the count exceeds 30,000.
Any ideas how to do it so that it should not be heavy when selecting a product for a campaign?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a through association to check the products count associated with it.

```
class Project
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :products, through: :campaigns

  PRODUCTS_LIMIT = 30_000
end
```

Now you may check this where you want to validate.

```
if @project.products.count <= Project::PRODUCTS_LIMIT
  'Good to go'
else
  'Error'
end
```

Comment: I do not have project model. I have only 2 models 'Campaign' and 'Product'.